# can I std::find a string in a stringstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, find, std

I have a stringstream that I'd like to iterate and determine if a substring exists in it.

I know that I could just convert to a string and do std::string::find(), but I was just hoping to avoid the conversion from stringstream to string if possible.

I understand the following won't work because the istream_iterator uses char as its type (not string)

```
stringstream ssBody;
string sFindThis;

...

auto itr = std::find (
    istreambuf_iterator<char>(ssBody),
    istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    sFindThis
);
```

But can I somehow search for a string in stringstream with std::find or similar without a conversion to string?

Comment: Use the string conversion. It is easy to comprehend, clean and fast.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing containers and streams. Streams are _flows of data_, not containers. Admittedly, stringstream breaks that abstraction slightly by allowing direct access to its full buffer, start to end ... but that doesn't mean you're using it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ standard does not define any `std::[io]?stringstream` methods for searching its contents.

Neither can you use `std::istreambuf_iterator` together with `std::search()`, since `std::istreambuf_iterator` is an input iterator, but `std::search()` requires a forward iterator.

The only effective way to search a string stream is to convert it to a `std::string`, first.

Comment: Streams don't _have_ "contents", that's why. (the abstraction leak that is stringstream::str notwithstanding)

Answer (score 2):

using pubsetbuf it is possible to associate a buffer with basic_stringbuf member and then search the buffer, however behavior of this function is implementation defined. explanations and the example are from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/setbuf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    char c[1024] = {};
    ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(c, 1024);
    ss << 3.14 << '\n';
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```